# Como faço código de potenciação no android?

Tags: java, android

Irei fazer uma calculadora que precisa de potenciação, alguém pode me dizer como é feito no android?

Comment: Já viu o pacote Java para funções matemáticas? Tem o método potenciação lá : [Math.pow](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_pow.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método estático `pow(dobule val1, double val2)` da classe `Math`:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(2.0, 3.0)); //2 elevado a 3
```

Saída:

> `8.0`